# JQuery how to change the string value of a textarea in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I m trying to change the string value of a textarea dynamically. In my code setValue function supposed to do it but whenever i try,the text area is being changed but getting not editable afterwards. 
What could cause the problem ?

```
   function createScriptPanel(value, container, mode) {
        var scriptPanel = $('<div id="editor"><textarea id="editor-code">' + value.script + '</textarea></div>').appendTo(container);
        CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function (cm) {
            CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.anyword);
        };
        sincapp.codeEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor-code"), {lineNumbers: true, matchBrackets: true, extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"}, mode: mode});
        scriptPanel.getValue = function () {
            return sincapp.codeEditor.getValue();
        };
        scriptPanel.setValue = function (newName,oldName) {

           var newValue= sincapp.codeEditor.getValue().replace(newName,oldName);

           $('#editor:nth-child(1)').html(newValue);
        };

        return scriptPanel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling html instead of val 
instead of $('#editor:nth-child(1)').html(newValue);
say $('#editor:nth-child(1)').val(newValue);

Answer (score 0):

It wasnt about the textarea but about CodeMirror, my mistake. Actually this worked pretty simple for me :

```
 sincapp.codeEditor.setValue(newValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
var newValue = sincapp.codeEditor.getDoc().setValue(newName);
```